# Makefile same target different inputs

Tags: makefile

This requirement is a pre run requisite to a bigger make system.
I cannot/ do not wish to change the system make, hence the need to have the output from this make have a single target.  Whilst I have many years of programming , I am a novice with regard to makefiles.  So any help is greatly appreciated.  Now on with the problem.

Firstly I don't want the the target being built if no inputs change. Exactly what a standard makefile is all about.

The problem I am having is getting the target built when the inputs do change. The inputs are comprised of EITHER an environment variable OR a couple of files.  NOTE The Environment variable is set outside the makefile.

Here are the scenarios.

1  Enviroment variable and files not changed.   Target not built.
2  Enviroment variable not changed. Files changed.   Target built.
3  Enviroment variable changed. Files not changed.   Target built.
4  Enviroment variable changed. Files changed.   Target built.

The problem I'm having is number 3.  How do I get the target to build when only the Environment variable changes from its previous setting. NOTE There is no problem in having the system maintain a file or setting containing the previous environment variable value to track the change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide your existing makefile attempt or give any details about which variables you care about, I'll just show how to write a "check env vars" recipe and leave it to you to embed it into your makefile.

Make deals with files, and the only kind of comparison it can make is file timestamps.  So, all prerequisite decisions must be expressed in terms of files and timestamps.

You can do this:

```
result: check-env.out $(SOMEFILES)
        touch $@

check-env.out : FORCE
        echo "$$SOMEVAR" > $@.new
        test -f '$@' && cmp -s '$@'.new '$@' \
            && rm -f '$@'.new \
            || mv -f '$@'.new '$@'
FORCE:
```

The `FORCE` prerequisite is used to ensure that the `check-env.out` recipe always runs.  However, it's only updated if the variable contents change, so the target that depends on it (`result` in this case) won't be updated due to this target if it hasn't changed.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Your use of the "environment" file was similar to what I had tried.  Mind you your coding is MUCH more elegant than what I had tried.  The FIX is as you said the FORCE prerequisite.  From now I I must remember to use the force